# Missing some of the environment variables

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am trying to create a Viewer with AutodeskPlattformService using the code on GitHub, and when I set the "client ID", "client secret" and "bucket name" on the aps-simple-viewer-nodejs folder and run "npm start", it says "Missing some of the environment variables. When I set the "client ID", "client secret" and "bucket name" on the nodejs-simple-viewer-nodejs folder and run "npm start", I get the message "Missing some of the environment variables.

- VScode is used.
- NET6 is installed.
- Link for reference: https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-simple-viewer-dotnet

Answer (score 0):

make a launch.json file under .vscode folder

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",   "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "pwa-node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\start.js",
      "env": {
        "APS_CLIENT_ID": "",
        "APS_CLIENT_SECRET": "",
        //   "GoogleAPIkey": "",
        "APS_CALLBACK_URL": "http://localhost:3000/api/forge/callback/oauth"
        /* "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:3000/api/forge/callback/oauth"     */
      }
    }   ] }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
The "launch.json" already exists in the ".vscode folder" and contains the following code
Where should I add the code you showed me?

{"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Server",
            "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "start"
            ],
            
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**/*.js"
            ]
}]}

Comment: Hi looks like you need to add the variables in .env file in the root folder. Make a .env file in the root folder and add APS_CLIENT_ID=,
        APS_CLIENT_SECRET= ,
        APS_CALLBACK_URL=http://localhost:3000/api/forge/callback/oauth

Comment: Thank you for your response!
I have a folder called "wwwroot". Should I create a ".env" file directly under this folder?
I would also appreciate it if you could tell me more about how to write in the ".env" file.

Answer (score 0):

1. First add launch.json file in .vscode folder

> ```
> {
>  "version": "0.2.0",
>   "configurations": [
>     {
>       "type": "pwa-node",
>       "request": "launch",
>       "name": "Launch Program",
>       "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
>       "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\start.js",
>       "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```

2. Create .env file in root folder
3. Enter this in .env file

> ```
> APS_CLIENT_ID= your client id
> APS_CLIENT_SECRET= your client secret
>  APS_CALLBACK_URL= http://localhost:3000/api/forge/callback/oauth
> ```

[image: Similar like this]

Comment: Thank you!
I tried following these instructions, but I still get "Missing some of the environment variables".

Comment: Book a meeting on calendly https://calendly.com/deepali-srivastava

Comment: I'm sorry.I don't know how to join meeting...

Comment: I can do it!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. First Install dotenv :
   npm i dotenv
2. Then in config.js file add at the first line :
   require('dotenv').config()
3. Create .env file in the root folder and add your variables :
   APS_CLIENT_ID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
   APS_CLIENT_SECRET=XXXXXXXXXXXXX